# Padding on right of page

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at: [http://www.aifittings.com](http://www.aifittings.com/home), there's padding on the right of the page, and I can't seem to find the offending element.

I've used

```
html {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

as a quick fix, but it's iffy at best and doesn't work on Google Chrome for iOS.  I was hoping someone might be able to lend another set of eyes and see if they might be able to spot where the issue is.  I'll update with any additional information if needed.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Other than that issue, you have a good looking website, Sir

Comment: ...I know @Quentin...but I figured I'd try and eek out a quick solution before the mods closed it...

Comment: @pennstate_fanboy Keep doing this, and you'll find yourself unable to ask questions at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this:

```
.scroll-bar .header-news{
left: 45px;
}
```

and it will get rid of your scroll bar

Replace it with:

```
.scroll-bar .header-news{
padding-left: 45px;
}
```

To get the same sort of effect, but without the scroll bar at the bottom of the page

Comment: Confirmed...thanks, will accept answer when I'm able... ~10 more mins.